# c# getting content from url after hitting a button

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve content from a website. Until now I did it using the following code :

```
static String getContent(String url)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    return client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Now, I have a page with buttons that lead to the content I actually want.
However, they don't have a full url as link, but only something like `javascript:check_eingabe('0');`.

How can I proceed to that target and get the information?

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 things here

1. You can not make a JavaScript method call from WebClient for the you may have to you web browser control and click button from code.
2. inspect the JavaScript method and inside the method if there's an web call like Ajax call if so you use that to get content.
3. If the JavaScript method just changes the display of content you want then it will be there in the page.